# Printer management view

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, frontend

This project involves setting up both the `backend` and `frontend` that allows users to interact with a simple `Printer` management view.

1. Create a free tier AWS account
2. Setup a database of your choice (RDS or DynamoDB)
   Create a single table to store the `Printers`
   The data you will be storing in the "Printers" table will include…

   - Printer name
   - Printer IP
   - Status (active / inactive)
3. Create the services required to perform basic CRUD on your `Printers`.
   How you achieve this is up to you, but this is an opportunity to show off your NodeJS skills, AWS Lambdas, GraphQL, AppSync and any other technologies you are comfortable using.
4. Create a ReactJS frontend that allows a user to perform basic CRUD on the Printers.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need help with the assignment

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)